# GMail: Add a link next to each attachment download link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm working on a chrome extensions whose purpose is to add a "export to gdocs" link to each attachment in gmail.

I've already implemented part of the code which successfully adds the link next to the "download" link, but I'm facing with a problem I don't know how to solve.

The problem is: **in a mail thread (with several replies), collapsed mails aren't affected by my script - and when they are expanded, the link is (as expected) not added**.

The reason why that occurs is that collapsed mails are loaded at runtime when expanded - so when my script is executed on page load there's no link to add as the mail content hasn't been loaded yet.

I tried adding an update handler using the prototype framework and the sample code I found here:

http://groups.google.com/group/prototype-scriptaculous/browse_thread/thread/5ad539212ea07716?pli=1 (last post)

http://jsbin.com/utuvu

but it doesn't work - although the solution itself is valid and working out of gmail.

The partially working solution is implemented using a chrome.tabs onUpdate listener (registered in the background file), and some jquery (injected as content script) which:

selects tables having the "cr hf" css classes (which are the ones used to contain the attachment links)

```
$('table.cf.hr').each(function() {
    injectLink($(this));
});
```

for each one, looks up the download link, extracts some parameters from the download url, 
create a new link and adds next to the last link

```
function injectLink(table) {
    var downloadLink = table.find("td:last a:last");
    var exportToGdocsLink = downloadLink.clone().attr(...)...
    ...
    downloadLink.after(exportToGdocsLink).after("<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>");
}
```

Has anybody implemented chrome extensions interacting with gmail? Any hint for me to figure out how to proceed?

**UPDATE**

The latest version of the code is this:

```
$('#canvas_frame').ready(function() { 
    var doc = frames['canvas_frame'].contentDocument; 
    $(doc).find('table.cf.hr').livequery(function() { 
        injectLink($(this)); 
    }); 
});
```

but I've tried several "combinations" - this is the "closest to what expected" result. The `canvas_frame` is the iframe containing the entire gmail interface. The table having css classes `cr hf` contains the attachment links.

Thanks
Antonio

Comment: Wouldn't jquery's `.live()` be able to solve it?

Comment: Never used that... but I wonder how it could help me - as far as I know there's no "update content" event. Any idea about what kind of event I should register using live()?

Comment: @Antonio - did you manage to solve this? Is your project open sources somewhere by any chance?

Comment: @Shaihi: no sorry, I didn't solve it. And it was for a client of mine, so I cannot disclose the sources, even if I didn't complete it.

Answer (score 2):

`.live()` would be helpful only if you are catching events.

You can detect element creation with [live query](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) jquery plugin.

Pure javascript solution would be listening to `DOMSubtreeModified` or `DOMNodeInserted` [events](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/) which fire whenever DOM changes (just need to be careful as there might be few hundreds of those at a time).

Comment: I tried the live plugin, but something odd happens. I spent several hours trying to figure out why it doesn't work, and casually I found out that it works, but not when I expect: my link is added only if I click on any of the other links added by my code. The js attached to the click event simply do an ajax call

Comment: @Antonio Can you put your new code into the question? I haven't dealt with gmail so I don't know all the specifics. I might only spot something on javascript side of things.

Comment: The latest version of the code is this:

    $('#canvas_frame').ready(function() {
        var doc = frames['canvas_frame'].contentDocument;

        $(doc).find('table.cf.hr').livequery(function() {
            injectLink($(this));
        });
    });

but I've tried several "combinations" - this is the "closest to what expected" result.

The canvas_frame is the iframe containing the entire gmail interface.
The table having css classes "cr hf" contains the attachment links.